# Need to pull daily min/max values from a year's worth of data-logger temperature data

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I'm a nurse manager for a big clinic system, and I need to find a way to pull daily min/max temperatures from a very large .csv file that has a temperature log of every 5 minutes for the past year (one row for each 5 minutes).  I tried automating it with "record macro" in excel but I can't figure out how to edit it so the selection range iterates as a variable (so it selects each day-at-a-time and reports the min and max for each day).  I used to know how to do this stuff when I was a CS student 20 years ago but I'm stuck.  Help a nurse out?

Comment: What about using MAXIFS and MINIFS? Or a pivot table?

Comment: Hmm I think I know how I could make that work if the date was it's own column but the date column looks like this:  2021-Mar-21 01:01 - also, more confusingly, not every date has the same number of 5-minute intervals associated with it

Comment: Yu can use `>="&DATE(2021,3,21)` and `<"&DATE(2021,3,22)` as criteria to isolate the rows associated with 2021-Mar-21.

Comment: Ok thanks, that makes sense - but I have like a year's worth of dates with a variable number of entries so I'm looking for a way to automate it so I don't have to slog through 100,000+ rows

Comment: @BigBen I was so excited to hear about a function I've never used before. Turns out I've never heard of it because its not in the version I own. *facepalm*. MaxIfs is new to Excel 2019 and Excel 365. I'm jealous.

Comment: We'd need a bit more info to help. Is the stored value (for example: 2021-Mar-21 01:01) a string, or is it a date time value that's formatted to look that way. If it's a string, you can use the `DateValue` function to get the date. If it's a datetime, you can take advantage of the fact that Excel stores date times as a decimal number. The whole number part is the day, and the decimal is the time. (All of this can be automated into a VBA script. Just need more details).

Comment: Create a pivot table. Or if that is not flexible enough, use Power Query (available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365)

Comment: I would also go with the pivot table approach. This will save you the time of trying to create a macro